# Group By and Inner Join Together To Get Unique Values By Maximum Date

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: Table and Desired Query]

I have a table here in which I want to write a SELECT query in SQL Server that allows me to get the following:

- For each unique combination of SalesPerson x Country, get only the rows with the latest Upload_DateTime

However, I am trying to do a group-by and inner join, but to no avail. My code is something like this:

```
SELECT t1.[SalesPerson], t1.[Country], MAX(t1.[Upload_DateTime]) as [Upload_DateTime]
  FROM [dbo].[CommentTable] AS t1
   GROUP BY t1.[SalesPerson], t1.[Country] 
  INNER JOIN SELECT * FROM [dbo].[CommentTable] as t2 ON t1.[SalesPerson] = t2.[SalesPerson], t1.[Country] = t2.[Country]
```

It seems like the GROUP BY needs to be done outside of the INNER JOIN? How does that work? I get an error when I run the query and it seems my SQL is not right.

Comment: `JOIN`s go in the `FROM` (after the initial object) and before the `WHERE`, not after the `GROUP BY`. Note the [syntax documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#syntax).

Comment: Unless you have any objects named *select*, `select` appears exactly once in a query.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, this subquery will fetch the person, the country and the latest date:

```
SELECT 
SalesPerson, Country, MAX(uplodaed_datetime)
FROM CommentTable
GROUP BY SalesPerson, Country;
```

This can be used on a lot of ways (for example with `JOIN` or with an `IN` clause).

The main query will add the remaing columns to the result.

Since you tried a `JOIN`, here the `JOIN` option:

```
SELECT
c.id, c.SalesPerson, c.Country,
c.Comment, c.uplodaed_datetime
FROM 
CommentTable AS c
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT 
SalesPerson, Country, 
MAX(uplodaed_datetime) AS uplodaed_datetime
FROM CommentTable
GROUP BY SalesPerson, Country) AS sub
ON c.SalesPerson = sub.SalesPerson
AND c.Country = sub.Country
AND c.uplodaed_datetime = sub.uplodaed_datetime
ORDER BY c.id;
```

Try out: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Z3ARInT-)

Comment: Thank you! This works. I didn't know the syntax of when to declare a variable with AS and when not to. It seems like AS was only used in the second part.